# Listing only custom post types with two required categories?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I use the following custom loop to display a custom post type with the custom taxonomy:

```
<?php // Create and run custom loop
    $custom_posts = new WP_Query();
    $custom_posts->query('post_type=page_content&page_sections=Apps');
    while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) : $custom_posts->the_post();
?>
    <div class="block-1">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Right now it reads: retrieve ONLY posts with the **page_content** custom post type and the 
**App** custom taxonomy.

Is it possible to make it read: retrieve ONLY posts with the **page_content** custom post type, the **Front Page** custom taxonomy, and the **Apps** custom taxonomy?

**EDIT:**

This didn't work:

```
<?php // Create and run custom loop
        $custom_posts = new WP_Query();
        $custom_posts->query('post_type=page_content&page_sections=Front Page, Apps');
        while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) : $custom_posts->the_post();
    ?>
        <div class="block-1">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In versions less the 3.1 you can't query more then one taxonomy using wp_query,  query_posts or get_posts.
However you can create your own sql query which you can see an exam[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155565/query-multiple-custom-taxonomy-terms-in-wordpress-2-8)ple here or use scribu's plugin http://scribu.net/wordpress/query-multiple-taxonomies/
To make it work.